# Netbeans 8.0.1 PHPUnity Generator

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I tryed install phpunit with netbeans and the installation done correctly! But, when a try generate the phpunit class, the follow error occurred: "The referenced parameter '--ansi' is not registered." and the file was not generated.

Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened the same to me. It seems that we were using the old phpunit-skelgen 1.2.1 version. Apparently, NetBeans 8.0.1 assumes you are using the newest version of phpunit-skelgen, that is 2.0.1.

So, you only have to update the phpunit-skelgen version, for example using this: https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-skelgen.phar

I copied that file to where I had my previous phpunit-skelgen.bat files: C:\xampp\php. Of course, this may vary according to your OS or your project structure.

After that, configure NetBeans to use the downloaded file instead of the old file. Something around Tools > Options in Netbeans menu.

Hope this helps!