# PHPUnit not working on netbeans "--ansi" is not registered

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, skeleton-code

When generating the Test with Netbeans I got the following ouput message error:

```
"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe" "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit-skelgen" "--ansi" "generate-test" "newPHPClass" "C:\Users\Alfonso\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PHPUnit_Test\newPHPClass.php" "newPHPClassTest" "C:\Users\Alfonso\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PHPUnit_Test\Tests\newPHPClassTest.php"
The referenced parameter '--ansi' is not registered.
Done.
```

However when I run,in the commandline, the following command:
 phpunit-skelgen --test newPHPClass
it works.

It seems netbeans does not run the proper command. How to correct this problem?

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121062/netbeans-8-0-1-phpunity-generator

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! Answer this question for the redirect and will give you props.